# How to determine app usage statistics for Android applications?

Tags: android, performance-testing

How do I determine the usage statistics of android applications such as the number of downloads, response time, battery usage statistics, average user time etc? I refer to statistics found on websites like similarweb.com. Is there any tool such as Alexa?

Comment: App analytics, vaguely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can go with any of them below,what you need to do is integrate their SDK  on your app

https://fabric.io/home

https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/provision/?authuser=0#provision/SignUp/

https://firebase.google.com/features/

and there are a number of other sdk's are available for the same

Comment: what if that application is not mine? such as that of a competitor?

Comment: there is no proper way to do .